# error while opening browser with selenium RC using JUnit

Tags: java, junit, selenium-rc

I am getting following error while opening browser with selenium RC using JUnit. Plz help.

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: XHR ERROR: URL = http://www.google.com/ Response_Code = 403 Error_Message = Forbidden
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:97)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting as `startURL` the Ip address of the site you want to test.

See also this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460371/hudson-selenium-plugin-getting-http-error-403-when-running-tests).

Comment: Even that is not working. I guess it has to do something with the proxy setting of browsers because I am accessing internet throgh proxy server. Do I need to mention that proxy server setting somewhere in Selenium RC.

Comment: @Arvind: maybe like `java -jar selenium-server.jar -Dhttp.proxyHost=my.proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=my_username -Dhttp.proxyPassword=my_password` as in http://wiki.openqa.org/display or http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#server-options/SRC/Proxy+Configuration+for+the+Selenium+Server